# Can you animate ng-show/ng-hide in angular 1.4.8?

Tags: angularjs

I currently animate my ng-enter, ng-leave for my ng-repeats, but how about for ng-show/hide? Are there classes for that too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalente classes for `ng-hide` and `ng-show` are `.ng-hide-add` and `.ng-hide-remove`. Also, you can use `.ng-hide-add-active` and `.ng-hide-remove-active` to set styles and control those states separatedely if you want.

According to Angularjs docs for [ngHide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) and [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) you can animate both using the same classes when it is on active state to produce animation with it's respective event (add or remove).

The following example implements a simple `fade-in` `fade-out` button using this feature.

> **Observations** Make sure to include `angular-animate.js` within the index page and also add `ngAnimate` module as dependency on your main module (or sub if it's a directive on an isolated module, lib, etc) like so: `angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);`

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('myController', function ($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.show = true;
    $interval(function () { $scope.show = !$scope.show; }, 1000);
  });

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);  
});
```

```css
.my-element.ng-hide{
  opacity: 0;
}

.my-element.ng-hide-add,
.my-element.ng-hide-remove {
    /* 
    setup animations 
    mess up with the properties, etc
    */
    
    transition: all linear 1s;
}

.my-element.ng-hide-add-active,
.my-element.ng-hide-remove-active {
    /* set state during transitions */
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController"><pre>show: {{ show }}</pre>
  <button class="my-element" ng-show="show">show</button>
</div>
```